# print only multiple line blocks

Tags: bash, awk, sed

the input is built of many lines blocks separated by an empty lines
I need to rid of single line blocks in print the remaining >1 lines blocks

exampe input:

```
block1

block2
block2
block2

block3

block4
block4

block5

block6
block6
```

expected output:

```
block2
block2
block2

block4
block4

block6
block6
```

Comment: It is always recommended to show your efforts which you have in order to solve your problem too on SO. Also I see you have never selected any answer as correct answer, once you have enough answers for your question try to select any answer out of them as correct answer too.

Answer (score 1):

You can play with `awk` *record separator*:

```
awk '$2!=""{print $0"\n"}' RS='' file
```

Answer (score 1):

This is easily done with [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) by redefining the field separator and the record separator.

First of all, it is important that realize that the two most important concepts to [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) are *records* and *fields*.

The input which is fed into awk through various means (`stdin` or `getline`) is read *record* by *record* where each record is separated by a record separator which is defined by `RS`. Since `RS` is by default the <newline > character `\n`, a record is actually a line and thus awk processes default a file line-by-line.

When a record/line is read, awk will split the record in fields where each field is separated by the field separator `FS` (which can be a regular expression). By default, the field separator `FS` is set to be any sequence of <blank> characters. Which means that, by default, each field is a word. If you redefine `FS`, fields will be different.

A special record separator is the empty one `RS=""` as it defines both `RS` and `FS`

> If `RS` is null, then records are separated by sequences consisting of a <newline> plus one or more blank lines, leading or trailing blank lines shall not result in empty records at the beginning or end of the input, and a <newline> shall always be a field separator, no matter what the value of `FS` is.
>
> **<sub>source: [awk POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html)</sub>**

So you can just do the following:

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS="";ORS="\n\n"}(NF>1)' file
```

Comment: This does not preserve the blank lines between.

Comment: @PaulHodges fixed

Comment: Interesting - separations are right, but you added a blank behind it rather than preserving the one before. Only the OP could say if that's fine; likely is, but my copy of the original file doesn't have the trailing line. If I add one, my solution doesn't preserve it. Huh.

Comment: @PaulHodges the trailing empty space is due to the print statement in awk which always appends an output record separator `ORS` after the string you want to print. And by default `(NF>1)` is equivalent to `(NF>1){print $0}` and that is where the `ORS` comes into play. I do not believe that this should be a big problem.

Comment: Me either. Just eyeballing details since the specs didn't *spec*ify, lol

Answer (score 1):

> In `sed`-

(edited from suggestions in the comments, many thanks) -

```
sed -n '
  /[^[:blank:]]/   H;
  /^[[:blank:]]*$/ { x; /.*[^[:blank:]].*\n.*[^[:blank:]].*/ { p; d; } }
  $                { x; /.*[^[:blank:]].*\n.*[^[:blank:]].*/ { p; n; } }
  ' infile

block2
block2
block2

block4
block4

block6
block6
```

> `/[^[:blank:]]/ H;` says

if there are nonblanks, append the pattern to the Hold space. (You can elaborate the check to make it more robust - I was going to example-simple.)

> `/^ *$/ { x; /.*[^ ].*\n.*[^ ].*/ { p; d; } }` says

`/^[[:blank:]]*$/ {` on blank lines,

- `x` swap the pattern and hold spaces; then
- `/.*[^[:blank:]].*\n.*[^[:blank:]].*/ {` *IF* there are newline-separated content lines with nonspaces,
- `p; d;` print and delete (which triggers the next read into the pattern space).
- `} }` close both open conditions.

> `$ { x; /.*[^[:blank:]].*\n.*[^[:blank:]].*/ { p; n; } }` says

`$ {` on the *last* line,

- `x` swap the pattern and hold spaces; then
- `/.*[^[:blank:]].*\n.*[^[:blank:]].*/ {` *IF* there are newline-separated content lines with nonspaces,
- `p; n;` print and go on, which will end the program.
- `} }` close both open conditions.

> That's it.

`sed` isn't exactly what I'd consider *ideally* "Turing complete" but it does have provisions for fairly complex logical processing. Hope this helps.

Comment: Note that this will preserve any leading blank lines, but not trailing ones.

Comment: Can't you merge the last two lines?

Comment: You would think, but one is every time it hits a blank line, and the other is a check once at the end of the file, which might not have a training blank line. If there are multiple lines in the last block but no blank line following, you still want it to print. Happy to see suggestions, but nothing comes to mind atm.

Comment: Be aware that your solution might fail if there are trailing spaces after the lines.

Comment: That's to account for the possibility (as in my file) of having no trailing newline at the end of the file. It still works. Is there a specific case that breaks?

Comment: Take the same input file, but add a space after the first `block4` and one before the second `block4`. Your regex should read : `/[^ ].*\n.*[^ ]/`

Comment: AHA! I see what you mean! Thanks a ton, friend. Although now that you point it out, I think maybe `/.*[^ ].*\n.*[^ ].*/` ?

Comment: I believe this is overkill, you are only interested if you can find two characters with a newline in between. The `.*` before and after are not needed. A bit safer might even be `[^[:blank:]][[:blank:]]*\n[[:blank:]]*[^[:blank:]]`

Comment: I initially let the code assume the lines would not have blanks, but if we're not doing that, then I don't want to assume the position of the blanks or the nonblanks. I just want to be sure there is a nonblank *somewhere* on the line. And yes, the classes are better, but I was keeping it simple when testing to make sure I didn't break the logic with a fumble-finger, lol. Will add that back in, too.

Answer (score 0):

Using Perl One-liner

```
> cat blocks.txt
block1

block2
block2
block2

block3

block4
block4

block5

block6
block6
> perl -ne ' BEGIN { $/="\n\n" } { print if /((.+?)\n)\1{1,}/ } ' blocks.txt
block2
block2
block2

block4
block4

block6
block6
>
```

One more variant if the file can fit into memory

```
> perl -0777 -ne ' { while(/((.+?)\n)\1{1,}\n?/g) { print "$&" } } ' blocks.txt
block2
block2
block2

block4
block4

block6
block6
>
```